# How do I concat a system call in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I want to concatenate a string inline with a system call. I cannot use an intermediate variable to hold the result because this makefile is autogenerated by qmake (which removes all user variables).

```
test:
        cp foo.exe $(system echo -n "foo`echo you`.exe")
```

Later I will replace `echo you` with a more complicated command, but this doesnt work as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where `system` comes from; that's not a valid function in GNU make.

Maybe you mean `shell`?

```
test:
        cp foo.exe $(shell echo -n "foo`echo you`.exe")
```